# How to get data from a mysql database using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, mysql, android

If possible, how can I get (and post) data from a mysql database using javascript? I know I can use php and other languages, but I just need to know if this is possible with javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to be way more specific, describing your particular task and reasons led you to this odd question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with Javascript. I could not find this with [server-side javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript) too.

Not sure about your exact requirement, but you can use Ajax to interact with database though some server side language.

Comment: For the purposes of speculation - aren't there some server-side JavaScript solutions that could possibly do this?

Comment: I'm using the phonegap framework to make mobile apps using web programming languages. only html and javascript can be used, so I'm trying to see how I can make use of a mysql database when I can only use javascript.

Comment: @amirrustam: That is unfortunate then but is suspect there should be some way, you need to look the docs of phonegap framework or ask for their support.

Answer (score 1):

If by Javascript you mean NodeJS on the server, this project might interest you http://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native - however the answers above are correct if you are talking about Javascript running inside a browser or other container.

If you want to run a vanilla javascript (for the concurrency speed) inside your own engine, I recommend looking at NodeJS and then using the NodeJS MySQL Native Driver that I linked above.

• http://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the "iPhone" and "Android" tags, I guess, you are trying to access the local storage databases on these platforms.

1. They don't use MySQL, but SQLite.
2. How you access them from the mobile browsers is described in the W3C draft documents for the local storage: http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/ for the local storage API or http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/section-sql.html#sql for the SQL API. It should be roughly the same API on iOS and Android since both of them use the Webkit browser engine.

Comment: actually they will be remote databases.

Answer (score 0):

javascript can get database from server 
if use AJAX , only a way is AJAX

Answer (score -1):

it is not possible, javascript is executed on the client.

you could make the javascript call something on the server (e.g. php script) that access the database though.

Comment: This is simply not true. There are serveral server side implementations of JavaScript. Have a look at http://nodejs.org

Answer (score -1):

The Web SQL database API isn’t actually part of the HTML5 specification, but it is part of the suite of specifications that allows us developers to build fully fledged web applications, so it’s about time we dig in and check it out.
Some examples are here

http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/

Comment: why does this need to access local memory? isn't it data on some sql server somewhere?

Comment: As part of HTML5 specs offline db access is the functionality. By using it you can do all CRUD on local database.

Comment: This API provides access to a local SQLite database, not a remote MySQL database.

Answer (score -1):

Do remove the tags iphone and android from this question. the tags are not relevant.

And only with javascript you cant accompolish this task , GET and POST request can be handled only by server side scripting languages like php.

Refer : http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost.shtml