# View data from MySQL to ListView in Android

Tags: android, mysql, listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get data from a mysql database using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352014/how-to-get-data-from-a-mysql-database-using-javascript)

I want to ask if you have ever made android project to view data from mysql server into listview in android?

Can you give me reference how to make that happen... Any reference is accepted...

I'm searching everywhere on the web but there's no good reference for it...

Comment: [Have a look here.](http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/displaying-mysql-data-into-listview-t53537.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean SQLite ? Since there is no mysql on android. A good blog here for Android+SQLite+ListView =>  [LINK](http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/android-using-the-sqlite-database-with-listview/)